# search an item in multidimentionnal array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find an element on a multidimentionnal array usin JAVASCRIPT function, but I get error

This is my array's data:

```js
export const datas = [
    {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        tables: [
            { ID: 11, title: 'Lorem' },
            { ID: 12, title: 'Ipsum' },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'Doe',
        tables: [
            {
                ID: 22,
                title: 'Arke',
                nodes: [{ name: 'Name1' }, { name: 'Name2' }, { name: 'Name3' }],
            },
            { ID: 23, title: 'Korem' },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        firstName: 'Brad',
        tables: [
            {
                ID: 30,
                title: 'Mern',
                nodes: [{ name: 'Name4' }, { name: 'Name5' }, { name: 'Name6' }],
            },
            {
                ID: 31,
                title: 'Full',
                nodes: [{ name: 'Name7' }, { name: 'Name8' }, { name: 'Name9' }],
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I've tried a reccursive function but it's not work, this is my code :

```js
export const findById = (arr, id) => {
    for (let o of arr) {
        if (o.tables.length > 0) {
            let a = findById(o.tables.nodes, 'id');
            console.log(a);
        }
    }
};
```

I want to print the Object with ID 22, the problem is that I don't have the same structure in each dimension, and it still confuse me..

My Input : 22

My output :

```js
{
    ID: 22,
    title: 'Arke',
    nodes: [{ name: 'Name1' }, { name: 'Name2' }, { name: 'Name3' }],
},
```

Have you an idea how to edit my function to get my input's response ?

Comment: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"You should **not force a tag into your title**. Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for."_

Comment: _"but it's not work"_ - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers **what the expected behavior should be**. Tell other readers what **the exact wording of the error message is**, and which **line of code is producing it**."_

Comment: @Andreas thank you for your article, I will read it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive function wasn't too far off, you need to check if the item as a tables first before recursively calling it again. And then finally just check the ID in the loop.

eg..

```js
const datas=[{id:1,firstName:"John",tables:[{ID:11,title:"Lorem"},{ID:12,title:"Ipsum"}]},{id:2,firstName:"Doe",tables:[{ID:22,title:"Arke",nodes:[{name:"Name1"},{name:"Name2"},{name:"Name3"}]},{ID:23,title:"Korem"}]},{id:3,firstName:"Brad",tables:[{ID:30,title:"Mern",nodes:[{name:"Name4"},{name:"Name5"},{name:"Name6"}]},{ID:31,title:"Full",nodes:[{name:"Name7"},{name:"Name8"},{name:"Name9"}]}]}];


function findById(arr, ID) {
  for (const a of arr) {
    if (a.tables) {
      const r = findById(a.tables, ID);
      if (r) return r;
    }
    if (a.ID === ID) return a;
  }
}

console.log(findById(datas, 22));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just need the nested data you can use flatMap and find

```js
const findById = (arr, id) =>
  arr
  .flatMap(d => d.tables)
  .find(t => t.ID === id)



const datas = [{
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'John',
    tables: [{
        ID: 11,
        title: 'Lorem'
      },
      {
        ID: 12,
        title: 'Ipsum'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Doe',
    tables: [{
        ID: 22,
        title: 'Arke',
        nodes: [{
          name: 'Name1'
        }, {
          name: 'Name2'
        }, {
          name: 'Name3'
        }],
      },
      {
        ID: 23,
        title: 'Korem'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Brad',
    tables: [{
        ID: 30,
        title: 'Mern',
        nodes: [{
          name: 'Name4'
        }, {
          name: 'Name5'
        }, {
          name: 'Name6'
        }],
      },
      {
        ID: 31,
        title: 'Full',
        nodes: [{
          name: 'Name7'
        }, {
          name: 'Name8'
        }, {
          name: 'Name9'
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(findById(datas, 22))
```

Comment: Thank you!! what if I want to return the element that contains name : 'Name5' ?
For example : I enter Name5 in my function and it's return me : 
{
        ID: 30,
        title: 'Mern',
        nodes: [{
          name: 'Name4'
        }, {
          name: 'Name5'
        }, {
          name: 'Name6'
        }],
      },

Comment: @Duchere you just have to modify the function inside find() like this t => !!t.nodes.filter(n => n.name === name)

Answer (score 1):

js has amazing array options https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

the ones which will help you most are probably:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

here are some examples

```js
// get the base with id 22
const baseWith22ID = datas.filter(f => f.tables.filter(s => s.id = 22))
// (i guess you want this one) get all elements with id 22
const onlyElementsWith22ID = datas.flatMap(f => f.tables.filter(s => s.id = 22))
```